# Python JSON filter by date key and write to new JSON file

Tags: python, json, mongodb

I have a Python script that will read through some JSON files and then import these to MongoDB.

I want it to only insert records that have the `Published` key 1 month or less.

My current code is:-

```
import json
import logging
import logging.handlers
import os
import pymongo
from pymongo import MongoClient


def import_json(mongo_server,mongo_port, vuln_folder):
    try:
        logging.info('Connecting to MongoDB')
        client = MongoClient(mongo_server, mongo_port)
        db = client['vuln_sets']
        coll = db['vulnerabilities']
        logging.info('Connected to MongoDB')
        basepath = os.path.dirname(__file__)
        filepath = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(basepath, ".."))
        archive_filepath = filepath + vuln_folder
        filedir = os.chdir(archive_filepath)
        file_count = 0
        for item in os.listdir(filedir):
            if item.endswith('.json'):
                file_name = os.path.abspath(item)
                with open(item, 'r') as currentfile:
                    vuln_counter = 0
                    duplicate_count = 0
                    logging.info('Currently processing ' + item)
                    file_count +=1
                    json_data = currentfile.read()
                    vuln_content = json.loads(json_data)
                    for vuln in vuln_content:
                        try:
                            del vuln['_type']
                            new_vuln = {key: vuln[key] for key in vuln if key != '_source'}
                            new_vuln.update(vuln['_source'])
                            coll.insert(new_vuln, continue_on_error=True)
                            vuln_counter +=1
                        except pymongo.errors.DuplicateKeyError:
                            duplicate_count +=1

                logging.info('Added ' + str(vuln_counter) + ' vulnerabilities for ' + item)
                logging.info('Found ' + str(duplicate_count) + ' duplicate records!')
                os.remove(file_name)
        logging.info('Processed ' + str(file_count) + ' files')
    except Exception as e:
        logging.exception(e)
```

I am thinking that I could do either an IF statement (Pseudo code!):

```
filter_vuln = if vuln.published = datetime.now -1:
              coll.insert(filter_vuln)
```

Which I am guessing it would drop any records not matching that pattern?

The JSON looks like this:

```
[
  {
    "_index": "bulletins",
    "_type": "bulletin",
    "_id": "OPENWRT-SA-000001",
    "_score": null,
      "lastseen": "2016-09-26T15:45:23",
      "references": 
      "affectedPackage": [
        {
          "OS": "OpenWrt",
          "OSVersion": "15.05",
          "packageVersion": "9.9.8-P3-1",
          "packageFilename": "UNKNOWN",
          "arch": "all",
          "packageName": "bind",
          "operator": "lt"
        }
      ],
      "edition": 1,
      "description": "Some Description",
      "reporter": "OpenWrt Project",
      "published": "2016-01-24T13:33:41",
      "modified": "2016-01-24T13:33:41",
  },
```

Some data has been removed from the above JSON for brevity as the actual record is quite long, and this is one of the shorter ones!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing that when you say within the last month you mean the last 30 days, you would need timedelta for this example.

from datetime import timedelta, datetime

today = datetime.now()

lastmonth = today - timedelta(days=30)

tests = ['2017-11-21','2017-10-20']

for date in tests:

```
if date >= str(lastmonth):
    print(date)
else:
    pass
```

The result is : 2017-11-21

## That's just an example on how to filter by date

Comment: So, to get it straight, the `tests` variable would actually be `new_vuln` from my code above?

Comment: yes it would be if vuln.published >= lastmonth:
              coll.insert(filter_vuln)

Comment: thats what I would use and have worked in the past, I'm no pro just sharing what I know

Comment: Hmm, that gives the error: 'dict' object has no attribute 'published'

Comment: oh yeah you have call the key, forgot about that